# Unable to deploy the vrfcoordinatorv2mock on the local development environment

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, chainlink

I am getting this error while deploying the Mock on development environment using brownie
`RFCoordinatorV2Mock.constructor confirmed (code size to deposit exceeds maximum code size)   Block: 1   Gas used: 1000000 (100.00%)`

I have tried to remove some functions defination which I'm not going to use but still even after reducing the code length to 248 lines I am still getting the same error.
How do I resolve it?

I have tried the reduce the code length and expected that it would work by doing so but, it is still not working.

Comment: Hi, can you describe steps you deployed mock contract? Which framework you are using? I don't think the error is that the size of mock contract is too large. Most likely the config of block size is set too small in your contract.

Comment: @FrankKong I am using the brownie framework and trying to deploy on the default development network using the depoy method.